# Angular 2 and Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, angular, angular2-template

I want to create a view using controls of the *Kendo UI*. Also, I use *Angular 2*.
So is it possible to integrate *Kendo UI* in views and components of the *Angular 2* haveing two-way data binding at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, KendoUI components are only available for Angular 1.X

Angular 2 is bringing a fundamental shift in the UI components paradigm, the KendoUi team are working on that and it will available later this year.

Here's a full roadmap http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-to-expect-in-2016-for-kendo-ui-with-angular-2-and-more

**-- UPDATE (8 Sep 2016) --**

On 9/14/2016 Telerik will be releasing a beta of Kendo UI for Angular 2, including :

```
Buttons (including Button and a ButtonGroup)
Dialog
Layout (TabStrip and PanelBar)
Inputs (Slider, Switch)
DropDowns (ComboBox, DropDownList)
DataViz (Preview)
Grid (Preview)
```